# How to make a div cover the whole width of a webpage, not just the viewport?

Tags: html, css, width, dreamweaver

I'm designing a website for a final project. One of the things I had included was a  navigation bar and a div with just a purple background to act as the header.

The problem is that when the window is anything less than fullscreen, the div doesn't reach the end. How can I make it so that the div reaches the end of the page even when the window is resized? Margins are set too zero by the way.

PS. I can't use position: fixed as the header is supposed to stay at the top, and I don't believe that vh or vw work as the program I use is too old. (Dreamweaver CS3)

Here's the code:(added jsfiddle) https://jsfiddle.net/0x4arjk2/8/

```
#apDiv5 {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:100px;
z-index:1;
background-color: #1A001A;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code you provided seems to work absolutely perfectly. I think you have other elements messing with this div. For example, if there is a parent div that has some width specified, then this header div will only take 100% that is made available by the parent. Try providing more code, or better a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Seems you're right, I put edited the post to include a fiddle, and it seems that my links might have something to do with it.

Comment: By "the div doesn't reach the end", you're meaning that your links are not aligned to the right?

Comment: No, what I mean is that the purple bar you see at the top doesn't reach the end of the window if the window isn't set to fullscreen. The links part was just me being lazy.

Comment: i'd suggest first that you build your layout without position:absolute, but display and a bit of float if really needed..... Once layout remade via display, it will be much easier to let parents and sibbling accords all together in the flow ...

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your markup is, you've absolutely positioned all of the divs, removing them from the element flow. Absolute positioning means positioning to the nearest positioned ancestor, instead of positioning to the viewport. So when the screen is resized, the topnav which is absolutely positioned tends to stay in its place and its content overflows in the x direction, hence showing the horizontal scroll bar. But the purple div's

```
width: 100%;
```

is inherited from the html tag, which is the width of the viewport. Hence, the observed effect.

You shouldn't absolutely position every div. An easy, responsive approach would be to use flex-box, assuming it can be used. It can automatically wrap all its elements when a certain width is reached which leads to a more responsive design. You can adjust this width (below which wrapping occurs) using

```
max-width: 100px; //some value
```

in the *headerMenu* div.

```css
html,
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        .header {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: baseline;
            justify-content: space-between;
            background-color: #1A001A;
        }

        .headerMenu {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            max-width: 1000px;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            align-items: baseline;
            background-color: #000;
        }

        .headerMenu a {
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        .headerMenu a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

        .headerMenu a.active {
            background-color: #FF0000;
            color: white;
        }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div>
            <!--add image/logo here-->
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="headerMenu">
            <a href="Splash.html">Home</a>
            <a href="Bio.html">Bio</a>
            <a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            <a class="active" href="upcoming Gigs.html">Upcoming Gigs</a>
            <a href="songs.html">Song List</a>
            <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
            <a href="media.html">Media</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Learn more about CSS flexbox [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-flexbox-everything-you-need-to-know-b4013d4dc9af)